# plasma frequency in terms of thermal energy

Tags: homework-and-exercises, plasma-physics, quark-gluon-plasma

The relativistic factor (in terms of momentum) is given by 
\begin{equation}\label{}
  \gamma=1/\sqrt{1-v^{2}/c^{2}}=\sqrt{1+p^{2}/m^{2}_{0}c^{2}},
\end{equation}

When thermal momentum is greater than the rest mass momentum ($p\gg mc^{2}$) then the plasma frequency and cyclotron frequency ($\omega_{p}=\sqrt{\frac{4\pi n e^{2}}{m}}$ and $\omega_{c}=\frac{eB_{0}}{mc}$) are defined as ($\omega_{p}=\sqrt{\frac{4\pi n e^{2}c}{p}}$ and $\omega_{c}=\frac{eB_{0}}{p}$). 
In ultra-rlativistic case, the thermal energy is greater than the rest mass energy i.e., $T\gg mc^{2}$. So
how to find the expression for the plasma frequency and cyclotron frequecy for the ultra-relativistic electron plasma in terms of the thermal energy, where $T$ is the thermal energy.  It should be $\omega_{p}=\sqrt{{4\pi n e^{2} c^{2}}/3 T}$ and $\omega_{c}={eB_{0}}/{T}$ for the ultra-relativistic case.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Plasma frequency seems to come from $mc^2 = 3T$ ($k=1$, mean energy per particle, ultra-relativistic case). Not sure about cyclotron frequency.

Comment: The cyclotron frequency, in the absence of electric/magnetic field gradients, is always defined as $$\Omega_{cs} = \frac{q_{s} \ B_{o}}{\gamma \ m_{s}}$$ where $s$ is the species (you can add a $c$ to the denominator if you prefer cgs).  I do not know where you got those versions other than they may be approximations of the version I wrote.